# Login in from Phone App

Tags: javascript, python, django, cordova, authentication

I have developed a Python/Django application for a company. In this app all the employees of the company have a username and a password to login in. Now there is a need for a phone application that can do some functionality.

In some functions I have the decorator @login_required

For security reasons I would like to work with this decorator than against it, so how do I?

I'm using PhoneGap (JavaScript/JQuery) to make the phone app if that helps. I can do my own research but I just need a starting point. Do I get some sort of token and keep it in all my HTTP request headers?

First Attempt:

I was thinking that maybe I POST to the server and get some kind of Authentication Token or something. Maybe there is some Javascript code that hashes my password using the same algorithm so that I can compare it to the database.

Thanks

Comment: use http://www.django-rest-framework.org/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you're using a phone application, you most likely are consuming data from a RESTful API or some sort of API. The easiest way to build a "safe" user system is to use the Token Authentication system from Django Rest Framework http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/authentication/#tokenauthentication.

Upon logging in, fetch the token and use the authorization header to authenticate your requests.

And to hook in easy login flows over a RESTFul API - https://github.com/Tivix/django-rest-auth

Note: Only use with HTTPS.

Comment: What do you mean by "safe"? Were there any exploits found in the rest framework?

Comment: Safe as in not easily hackable, "secure" might be the better word. Token auth with HTTP is dangerous, since if anyone sees your unencrypted traffic over HTTP, they could just sniff out a user's token and pretend to be that user. Basically what you'd expected with any authentications system

Answer (score 0):

You would need to either expose the django token in the settings file so that it can be accessed via jquery, or that decorator wont be accessible via mobile. Alternatively, you can start using something like oauth